# How drag-gable item can delete using react-native-shortable-grid in react-native?

Tags: react-native

When I use react-native-sortable-grid at that time I faced one issue like I not able to delete any item.

```
<SortableGrid
                        blockTransitionDuration={400}
                        activeBlockCenteringDuration={200}
                        itemsPerRow={3}
                        onDeleteItem={data => console.log('Item was deleted:', data)}
                        dragActivationTreshold={200}
                        onDragStart={() => console.log('Some block is being dragged now!')}
                        onDragRelease={data =>
                            console.log(
                                'Drag was released, the blocks are in the following order: ',
                                data,
                            )
                        }>
                        {this.state.data.map((letter, index) => (
                            <View
                                key={index}
                                onTap={() => console.log("Item number:", index, "was tapped!") }
                                style={[styles.block, { backgroundColor: this.getColor() }]}>
                                <Image source={letter.image} style={{ height: 80, width: 80, marginTop: 20, resizeMode: 'contain' }} />
                                <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 15, }}>{letter.title}</Text>
                            </View>
                        ))}
                    </SortableGrid>
```

//toggleDeleteMode() is called during onTap in this example

[image]

Comment: please explain more what you are looking for ???

Comment: I won't delete draggable image.

Comment: when you want to delete it ondrag or click ???

Comment: I want image on the top corner close touchable opacity When I clicked then it will delete.

Comment: i can not see in image that you are using any  top corner close button in your each item here.where is your close button

Comment: I'm not adding this button but I required to add a close button onto the image

Comment: ya you can put small delete button with absolute position and you can add you delete code on that button

Comment: ok, I want to code for this or once I clicked that button Image can be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did implement delete functionality on images.

try to use this code

```
<SortableGrid
                            blockTransitionDuration={400}
                            style={{ flex: 1 }}
                            activeBlockCenteringDuration={200}
                            itemsPerRow={3}
                            dragActivationTreshold={200}
                            onDragRelease={() => { this.setState({ scrollEnabled: true }) }, (itemOrder) => itemOrder}
                            onDragStart={() => { this.setState({ scrollEnabled: false }) }}
                            onDeleteItem= { (item)=>  item }
                            ref={'SortableGrid'}
                        >
                            {this.state.data.map((letter, index) => (
                                <View
                                    ref={'itemref_' + index}
                                    onDoubleTap={this.startDelete}
                                    key={index}
                                    style={[styles.block, { backgroundColor: this.getColor() }]}>
                                    <Image source={letter} style={{ height: 80, width: 80, marginTop: 20, resizeMode: 'contain' }} />
                                    <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 15, }}>{letter}</Text>
                                </View>
                            ))}
                        </SortableGrid>
```

[image: like this]